# Tasks app keeps starting on login

Tags: appcenter, default, horus

I'm on Elementary OS 7 (Horus). The last few days the default Task app (io.elementary.tasks) keeps opening/starting on startup. If I remove is from the startup applications (in settings -> applications), it re-appears on next boot.

Today I tried to uninstall, but I can't using the AppCenter (it keeps being in an installed state). I don't mind the app being there as long as it doesn't bother me. And since I don't use it, it bothers me by starting and showing up after I log in.

Right now I just renamed the executable:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/io.elementary.tasks /usr/bin/io.elementary.taskz
```

But is there a better way of removing the app on startup or uninstalling? That this happens is probably a bug, I guess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also check these two folders as they contain autostart items:

- ~/.config/autostart
- /etc/xdg/autostart

If you find `io.elementary.tasks.desktop` file there either rename it or delete it.